# Chance of Drawing All of a Subset

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory, percentages

I have a simple question but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere. Say that I have a set $\mathbb Z$ and a subset of that $\mathbb X$.

I want to draw elements from $\mathbb Z$ until there is at least a 50% chance that I have drawn all the elements of $\mathbb X$.

Clearly if $|\mathbb X| = 1$ then I just need to draw $\frac{|\mathbb Z|}{2}$.

But how many will I need to draw if $|\mathbb X| > 1$?

**EDIT:**

[GBQT made a good comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1410298/chance-of-drawing-all-of-a-subset#comment2873422_1410347), I'm talking about drawing with replacement. Drawing element $e$ from $\mathbb Z$ does not preclude $e$ from being drawn again on subsequent draws. But $\mathbb X$ is finite, as in it has each element of $\mathbb X$ is unique.

Comment: Maybe you could start by finding the chances of drawing every element of $X$ when you draw $n$ elements of $Z$?

Comment: @GBQT If I could guarantee that $n \geq |\mathbb X|$ that would certainly solve the problem. But that's exactly what I can't figure out how to do.

Comment: @thanasissdr Yup I'll edit.

Comment: @Jonathan Mee Well, if $n< |\mathbb X|$, then the chance of drawing every element of $\mathbb X$ is 0. Now what if $n \geq |\mathbb X|$?

Comment: If $Z$ is an infinite set, then what $\frac{|Z|}{2}$ equals to?

Comment: If you are drawing *with replacement*, as the edit seems to indicate, then it's **not** true that you just need to draw $|\mathbb{Z}|/2$ times when $|\mathbb{X}|=1$.

Comment: @BarryCipra Ah, I see your point. When I did the logic for that I did think about that as though I had to get a distinct element with each draw. I need to rethink that.

Comment: @BarryCipra After rethinking I realized that the equation above is correct. The probability of each draw getting the only element of $\mathbb X$ is $\frac {1}{|\mathbb Z|}$. Since the number of successes I need is 1 $\frac {|\mathbb Z|}{2|\mathbb X|}$ is the actual equation but $|\mathbb X| = 1$. This helped me understand: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/probability/random-variables-topic/binomial_distribution/v/expected-value-of-binomial-distribution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of draws is the unknown here, it will be represented by the variable $x$. If $x < |\mathbb X|$ then the chance of drawing all elements of $\mathbb X$ is 0%. Otherwise the chance of drawing all elements of $\mathbb X$ is: All combinations with repetition that can be made from $\mathbb Z$ of size $x - |\mathbb X|$, divided by all combinations with repetition that can be made from $\mathbb Z$ of size $x$.

[Combination with Repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition) can be calculated by the [Binomial Coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient): $\binom {n + k - 1}{k}$ Where $n$ is the size of the set and $k$ is the size of the combinations.

So the equation this question asks for is actually: $$\frac {\binom {|\mathbb Z| + x - |\mathbb X| - 1}{x - |\mathbb X|}}{\binom {|\mathbb Z| + x - 1}{x}} = 0.5$$

That already looks hairy, and it doesn't bet nicer as it's expanded out: $$\frac {(|\mathbb Z| + x - |\mathbb X| - 1)!x!}{(|\mathbb Z| + x - 1)!(x - |\mathbb X|)!} = 0.5$$

Really the only way that this can be simplified is removing the constants: $$\frac {(|\mathbb Z| + x - |\mathbb X|)!x!}{(|\mathbb Z| + x)!(x - |\mathbb X|)!} \frac {|\mathbb Z| + x}{|\mathbb Z| + x - |\mathbb X|} = 0.5$$

Alternatively it could be visualized as: $$\frac{\underset {i = x - |\mathbb X| + 1}{\overset {x}{\LARGE \mathrm \Pi}}i}{\underset{i = |\mathbb Z| + x - |\mathbb X|}{\overset {|\mathbb Z| + x - 1}{\LARGE \mathrm \Pi}}i} = 0.5$$